# Zero-based formatting for week moment.js is not available

Tags: momentjs

So I am pulling in a date from MySQL db. 
I receive date of "2020-00" for example
I need to compare that to a moment formatted string but moment starts at 1 instead of zero.
How can I use moment to use zero-based formatting?

Bottomline is that I am comparing "2020-01" to "2020-00"

```js
const moment = require('moment');
const string = "2020-01-01"

let tzdate = moment("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")

tzdata = tzdate.format('YYYY-ww');

console.log(tzdata)
```

Comment: what does "2020-00" signify?

Comment: It is the first week of the year. From MySQL db first week is 2020-00 but in moment the first week is 2020-01.